# Specified Type casting is not valid

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
htmlCol2 = Re_new_webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
```

The exception:

> Specified Type casting is not valid

I want to get the `htmlElement` tag of website to autoclick, by clicking on the button of my desktop application (windows form application C#)

Comment: I've modified your question to remove the code from the title and improve formatting, however `Re new` isn't valid C# syntax so I made a best guess at what this was supposed to be, please correct it if I was wrong

Comment: `GetElementsByTagName` returns a collection of HTML elements. Why are you casting that to some `Re` which definitely *isn't* return by `GetElementsByTagName`?

Comment: @Sayse Re_new_webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"); this is the actual code, above re new may be post mistakenly

Comment: @ah I see so you have a `WebBrowser` called `Re_new_webBrowser1`, apologies, I will fix this for you, either way the code you provided won't reproduce this error on its own, you need to include more information

Comment: @Luaan 
 htmlCol2=Re_new_webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            
            foreach (HtmlElement submit2 in htmlCol2)
            {
                 if (submit2.GetAttribute("name").Equals("go"))
                {
                    submit2.InvokeMember("click");
                    MessageBox.Show("First repost method"); 
                    break;
                }
            }

Comment: Looks fine. What type is `htmlCol2`?

Comment: @Luaan 
HtmlElementCollection htmlCol2=Re_new_webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

Comment: Where does it throw the error? On the `foreach`? `Equals`?

Comment: @Luaan at this line
htmlCol2=Re_new_webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of problems. First with your question, you do not tell what type (Re) could be, what type htmlCol2 is.

Then you new it up, which is incorrect.

And also, you try to mix htmlElements and WPF forms which can conflict on the namespace of input items.

Provide more code, preferrably the complete code of a new project where you try to reproduce this problem.

Comment: htmlCol2 = Re_new_webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
             
            foreach (HtmlElement submit2 in htmlCol2)
            { 
                if (submit2.GetAttribute("name").Equals("go"))
                {
                    submit2.InvokeMember("click");
                    MessageBox.Show("First repost method Done"); 
                    break;
                }
            }

Comment: Pieter, I mis-edited the OP's question originally as the underscores were lost when the op wrote their question, also it would seem they are creating a `winforms` application.